# Prevent Visual Studio from adding projects to Recent items in the task bar

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, visual-studio-2012, jumplist

Whenever I pick up an individual project in Visual Studio (e.g. to add it to a solution) the project is added to the "Recent" items in the task bar. For me, this is totally useless, because I never open individual projects in VS, only solutions.

Is anybody aware of a way to prevent VS projects from being added to this Recent list?

I can find tons of posts on the Internet explaining how I can prevent applications as a whole to add items to Recent items and MRU lists and of course I know I can remove items manually from this list. But I'd like to prevent specifically VS project files from being added.

Comment: Try asking this on www.stackoverflow.com - this is also on topic over there.

Comment: @spike.y Questions like this get closed there in no time. It's not a programming-related issue.

Comment: oh, I thought it was allowed over there because http://stackoverflow.com/tour says you can ask about Software Development Tools.

Comment: I have found a page that may give you an idea of how you can modify some values. I don't know if this will work but here's the link http://alinconstantin.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/windows-7-jump-lists-and-visual-studio.html - that's all I got. I must go now, as I have a mountain of work to catch up on.

Comment: Thanks @spike.y, but this is still "all or nothing". I think I have to live with it.